# Need help setting a class's real value equal to the parameter passed to the method in java

Tags: java, getter-setter

```
public Complex(String cStr){
    this(cStr.split("(?=\\+)|(?=\\-)"));  // splits cStr at + or - into an 
    // array of strings having two elements.  The first element of the 
    // resultant array will be the real portion, while the second is the 
    // imaginary portion.  This array is passed to the next constructor.


How do I determine what the complex number itself is?

    // TODO: Write a getter called getComplex() that returns this Complex number itself.  
    // NOTE: you must return a Complex type, not a String type.



}
```

If anyone could provide any assistance with any part of this code it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Whoops I set the title wrong sorry

Comment: can you please provide some input string's and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters I would define the whole class. So possibly something like this:

```
class Complex {
    float real, img;

    public Complex(float real, float img) {
        this.real = real;
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

After that you can do what you want pretty easily:

```
public Complex(String real, String img) {
    this(Float.parseFloat(real), Float.parseFloat(img));
}

public Complex(String str) {
    String[] components = str.split("(?=\\+)|(?=\\-)");
    this(components[0], components[1]);
}
```

Your question isn't very clear but I guess this is what you're going for. I would suggest writing a static method called `Complex.parseComplex(String str)` because this is the standardized way in java for parsing number types from strings.
I hope this helps!